# What is the best way to handle OnResize in FMX?

Tags: delphi, resize, delphi-xe5, firemonkey-fm3

When a window is resized I want to handle the OnResize event when resizing is finished as updating the graphic takes seconds. That is tricky because resizing a window generates lots of resize events. As updating the window takes a while I don't want the window being updated on each event. I tried to detect a mouse up to flag that as the event that finishes a resize but the mouseup is never detected.

TLama had a [nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645339/how-to-detect-when-form-resizing-starts-and-stops) but alas, that's VCL, I need it for Firemonkey. Any suggestions for FMX?

Answer (score 2):

What about something similar to the [Debounce() or Throttle() function in Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce)? Both functions provide ways to limit how regularly a procedure is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to handle it in FMX on Windows, you need to change your form to inherit from `TResizeForm` and assign `OnResizeEnd` property. Not very clean since it depends on on FMX internals, but should work.

```
unit UResizeForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Forms, FMX.Platform.Win;

type
  TResizeForm = class(TForm)
  strict private
    class var FHook: HHook;
  strict private
    FOnResizeEnd: TNotifyEvent;
  public
    property OnResizeEnd: TNotifyEvent read FOnResizeEnd write FOnResizeEnd;
    class constructor Create;
    class destructor Destroy;
  end;

implementation

uses Winapi.Messages;

var
  WindowAtom: TAtom;

function Hook(code: Integer; wparam: WPARAM; lparam: LPARAM): LRESULT stdcall;
var
  cwp: PCWPSTRUCT;
  Form: TForm;
  ResizeForm: TResizeForm;
begin
  try
    cwp := PCWPSTRUCT(lparam);
    if cwp.message = WM_EXITSIZEMOVE then
    begin
      if WindowAtom <> 0 then
      begin
        Form := TForm(GetProp(cwp.hwnd, MakeIntAtom(WindowAtom)));
        if Form is TResizeForm then
        begin
          ResizeForm := Form as TResizeForm;
          if Assigned(ResizeForm.OnResizeEnd) then
          begin
            ResizeForm.OnResizeEnd(ResizeForm);
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  except
    // eat exception
  end;
  Result := CallNextHookEx(0, code, wparam, lparam);
end;

class constructor TResizeForm.Create;
var
  WindowAtomString: string;
begin
  WindowAtomString := Format('FIREMONKEY%.8X', [GetCurrentProcessID]);
  WindowAtom := GlobalFindAtom(PChar(WindowAtomString));
  FHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, Hook, 0, GetCurrentThreadId);
end;

class destructor TResizeForm.Destroy;
begin
  UnhookWindowsHookEx(FHook);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround add a `TTimer` to the form, set its initial state to disabled and the `Interval` property to `100` ms. To minimize the amount of times your application reacts to the `OnResize` event use the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
    with ResizeTimer do
    begin
        Enabled := false;
        Enabled := true;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ResizeTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ResizeTimer.Enabled := false;

    // Do stuff after resize
end;
```

The minimal delay should not be noticeable by the user.